# I can not figure out functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, user-input

So I want to use function that will request a string like a login function, but when I want to test if the function works I can’t get the user input to be printed. Can someone explain please ?

```
def some():
    x = input()

some()
print(x)
```

Comment: You need to return to your tutorials and review how to communicate values between a function and the calling program.  In this case, you need to return a value.  Simply giving two different variables the same name, does not do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Use return statement in function and scope of x is inside the function:

```
def some():
    x = input()
    return x

y = some()
print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot  it surfe will help me a Lot